# How to keep login state in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, authentication, state

How to keep login state in silverlight. Like we store information in Cookies in ASP.net Application.

Answer (score 0):

A Silverlight application runs in the client browser and is tied to this specific user. So you can keep this information wherever you like: static fields, helper classes, singletons, ... without risking to mix with other users.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state whether you mean keep login state transiently, or across restarts of the Silverlight application.

If the former, you can just store it in a variable. The Silverlight process runs on the client machine and thus has a one-to-one relationship with that user.

If the latter, you could consider storing a token in isolated storage. When the application starts, you can check for the presence of this token and pass it to the server if found.